# Should I include <6 months of previous experience where I got terminated for a missed day at work?

Tags: termination

The whole situation is a bit more complicated than that. I got terminated because of a missed day but I had other complications as well (a major work accident). So although I did get terminated because I missed a day of work, I think that decision was mutually for the best, as I felt that we did not have a good relationship after that incident anyways.

Now my question is regarding my current cv, should I be include that experience and try to justify that it was mutually for the best?

I have to add that prior to working at this new company, I was at another employer for about 2 years where I built an extremely positive relationship with my direct manager, and after losing my job at the new employer, my previous manager took me back right away.

I'm quite confused as to what I should do.

Comment: why dont you negotiate with your employer to hide the break any ways he took you back?

Comment: Also related: [Would you include short work experience in your CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/973/would-you-include-short-work-experience-in-your-cv)

Answer (score 3):

If you're back working for your earlier employer, it isn't clear you need to change much in your CV.  If you have a good working relationship somewhere - good enough that 'they take you back', ignore the bad interval.  You might make some one or two line reference to work done on a project - if you accomplished something.  If it was overall a waste of time and effort, leave it off.