# How to include work experience on resume

Tags: resume, work-experience, travel

I am writing my resume for a travel position, I have only ever waitressed but have a passion for travel. I have completed a weeks paid work experience for a luxury Destination Management Company which I would love to include on my resume just not sure how. The company had intended on taking me on but due to situations in the company where I live they were not able to. Does anyone have any suggestions? Also would it be an idea to include a reference from the company?

Thanks,

Comment: Related: [Would you include short work experience in your CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/973/would-you-include-short-work-experience-in-your-cv)

Comment: Remember the CV is where you sell yourself. Besides working for this company for one week (maybe it's too short to be a good sell), what can you write to sell your skills to the places you're applying to?

Comment: Do you not have the possibility to get a recommandation letter from this company ? It might help !

Answer (score 2):

A possible option...

Have a section of your resume "Additional Experience". List the year and month you worked for Destination Management Company and a description of hopefully some project/work you did for them during that week. In interviews, you can just explain you had the opportunity to work on X task for them, really enjoyed it, and it's what's making you want to go into the field. You can explain the geographic issues that prevented them from taking you on assuming none of those would reflect badly on you.

That way it looks like a task/project you did, not like a 1 week job stint. Definitely don't lie that it was only a week, but framing it as the experience gained rather than short term employment might get you past the HR barrier. You probably want this at the top of your resume above waitressing unless there are some education/certifications that are related that you could list first.